# The thread has exited with code 1: Join() and Detach()

Tags: c++, multithreading

I developing a software that needs to download several images and do some processing with opencv. I'm using curllib to download the images.So basically I get the images from different network cameras. What I want to do is download these images simultaneously, so I'm trying to use `detach()` and call the the curllib. The main reason I'm trying to use `detach()` is to do not wait for some download that can take longer or timeout. So I want to process what is available in the main loop. When I use `detach()`, after while the program stops without any error or exeption just showing:

```
The thread .... has exited with code 1 

The thread ....has exited with code 1
```

and after:

```
The program.... has exited with code 1....
```

No exceptions, no errors, nothing. just it.

If I change to `join()` it never stops. But with join I need to wait all threads download all images or timeout.

I will show an example with two requisitions:

```
//create class
ProcessImage* camera1 = new ProcessImage;
ProcessImage* camera2 = new ProcessImage;

for (;;) {

  /* Must initialize libcurl before any threads are started */
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  // Load Image into Class variable
  std::thread th(&ProcessImage::loadimage, camera1);
  if (th.joinable()) {
    th.detach();
  }

  std::thread th2(&ProcessImage::loadimage, camera2);
  if (th2.joinable()) {
    th2.detach();
  }

  // Process with Opencv
  camera1->run();
  camera2->run();

}
```

My load image function:

```
void ProcessImage::loadimage() {


    Mat loading;

    //insert user and password
    string password = ConfigData.username + ":" + ConfigData.password;

    // Loading image with Curl
    loading = curlImgClass(ConfigData.urlSnapshot.c_str(), password.c_str(), 5);


    lastfail = false;

    // Internal variable to store the downloaded image 
    img = loading.clone();


    if (loading.empty()) {

        lastfail = true;
        endoperation = true;

    }

    if (loading.total() < 500) {

        lastfail = true;
        endoperation = true;


    }
}
```

Curl Functions:

```
size_t  ProcessImage::write_dataClass(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    vector<uchar> *stream = (vector<uchar>*)userdata;
    size_t count = size * nmemb;
    stream->insert(stream->end(), ptr, ptr + count);
    return count;
}

cv::Mat  ProcessImage::curlImgClass(const char *img_url, string userpass, int timeout)
{

    vector<uchar> stream;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, img_url); //the img url
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); // pass the writefunction
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &stream); // pass the stream ptr to the writefunction
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // timeout if curl_easy hangs,
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);


    if (userpass != ":") {
        const char * c = userpass.c_str();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, c);
    }

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); // start curl
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); // cleanup

    /* Check for errors */
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {

        //return imdecode(stream, -1); // 'keep-as-is'
        cv::Mat test(cv::Size(1, 1), CV_64FC1);
        return test; // 'keep-as-is'
    }
    else {
        return imdecode(stream, -1);
    }
}
```

What can I do to make it work with `detach()`?
I tried a lot of controls like `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` but nothing works, the software keep quitting.

editing:  the only variable I use in both function is the `img` :

```
int ProcessImage::run(){

        if ( (img.total() < 500)  || (lastfail == true)) {

            failcount = failcount + 1;

                // create a black window
                Mat imagefail(480, 640, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

               // putText(imagefail, "Connection Fail", cvPoint(480 / 2, 480 / 2), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 1, 8, false);

                imshow(ConfigData.name.c_str(), imagefail);                
                waitKey(20);

                m_lock2 = false;

                std::cout << "connection fail \n";

                return -1; // load fail
            //}

        }
        else {

            failcount = 0;
        }



        Mat sendimage = img.clone();
        Mat opacity = sendimage.clone();

       //// do other stuff with sendimage now ////

}
```

Comment: Detaching threads rarely is a really good idea. Maybe using timed promises and futures is a better design.

Comment: Consider a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) rather than spinning up a new thread for each transaction. The thread pool is created at start-up and the rest of the code assigns it jobs to perform. This keeps you from having to manage or micromanage threads and makes it easy to tie the number of threads in the pool to a optimum count, like the number of cores available.

Comment: Can you show `run()`?  Most likely you are hitting a data race.

Comment: @user4581301 I will search about it. Thanks

Comment: @NathanOliver I edited with the run function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  `loadimage` populates `img` and `run` reads from `img` without any synchronization.  This cam cause all sorts of issues,one of them being what you are currently observing.  To fix this you need to use some sort of synchronization to make sure you aren't reading while you are writing.  The simplest method is to move `loadimage` and `run` into a single thread.  That way they will get ran consecutively per object so there is no chance you'll get a data race.  That would change your for loop to look like

```
//create class
ProcessImage* camera1 = new ProcessImage;
ProcessImage* camera2 = new ProcessImage;

for (;;) {

  /* Must initialize libcurl before any threads are started */
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  // Load Image into Class variable and process
  std::thread th([](){ camera1->loadimage(); camera1->run(); });
  std::thread th2([](){ camera2->loadimage(); camera2->run(); });


  // join or detach threads, if wanting to detach consider using a thread pool or adding threads to a container instead
  th.join(); // possibly detach
  th2.join(); // possibly detach

}
```

I used `join` in the code but `detach` might be needed if you don't want to wait.  That said you can fix that problem by storing the threads in a container and then before the program exits call join on all the threads to make sure everything is done before the application terminates.  You could also leverage a thread pool for that.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try your solution